# Sql Query With FOR XML

Tags: sql

I have a query

```
SELECT Brand,
        UEI_ID,
        Concat_Prd_Id = Stuff((
                        SELECT ',' + CAST(Second_ID AS VARCHAR(max))
                        FROM Temp1 t2
                        WHERE t1.Brand = t2.Brand
                                AND t1.UEI_ID = t2.UEI_ID
                        FOR XML Path('')
                        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM Temp1 t1
GROUP BY Brand,
        UEI_ID
```

Which is taking 8.48 Min to executing 26,000 Records.

Please let me know how to reduce the time ... ?

Comment: do you have an index on this column `Brand`?

Comment: Please post the execution plan.

Comment: No i dont have Index on both the coloumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly add an index, (depeneding on other queries you use that reference the table) something like the below should do it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Temp1 ON Temp1 (Brand, UEI_ID) INCLUDE Second_ID
```

Although I don't think it is applicable to your situation since `Second_ID` is probably an integer, and it won't improve execution time, it is good habit to use the XML `value` to account for concatenating strings with special characters in.

e.g.

```
SELECT Brand,
        UEI_ID,
        Concat_Prd_Id = STUFF((
                        SELECT ',' + CAST(Second_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                        FROM Temp1 t2
                        WHERE t1.Brand = t2.Brand
                                AND t1.UEI_ID = t2.UEI_ID
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)', 1, 1, '')
FROM Temp1 t1
GROUP BY Brand,
        UEI_ID
```

Comment: hear Brand and UEI_ID have a dublicate data so i cant add index on them

Comment: Indexes do not have to be unique, so there is no reason not to index them.

Comment: Hi, I traied to creat Index on the Field but got error. Due to data type size (it was nvarchar(Max)). I changed size and added index now the query is much more faster, thanks

Comment: If this has solved your problem then please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this lets the community know your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't add an `Index` on `BRAND` and `UEI_ID`, you can alter the table by using this syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX indexName (columnName);
```

So in your case, you can do this

```
ALTER TABLE Temp1 ADD INDEX IDX_Brand (Brand);
ALTER TABLE Temp1 ADD INDEX IDX_UEI_ID (UEI_IDd);
```